# MLE with vectors as arguments

Tags: r, mle

I'm trying to use the `mle()` function in R, but it seems the start list argument can only be a list of single elements, not vectors.

Is there a way I could pass a list of vectors?

Below is what I have currently:

```
inits <- list(position=c(-0.5,0.5,0.2,
               -0.2,0.3,-0.3,0.4,0), 
 weight=c(5,1), 
 beta=c(-1,-1), 
 prob_s=c(0.5,0.5))

fit <- mle(LL, start = inits)
```

My LL function looks as below:

```
LL <- function(position, weight, 
               beta, prob_s)
```

Comment: What is your `LL`?

Comment: Updated original post to include function signature.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the `mle()` function from the `stats4` package, then as far as I know you can't have vector parameters.  What you can do is wrap your `LL()` function in another function that is passed to `mle()`.  For example,

```
LL1 <- function(position1, position2, position3, position4, 
                position5, position6, position7, position8,
                weight1, weight2, 
                beta1, beta2,
                prob_s1, prob_s2)
         LL(position = c(position1, position2, position3, position4, 
                position5, position6, position7, position8),
            weight = c(weight1, weight2),
            beta = c(beta1, beta2),
            prob_s = c(prob_s1, prob_s2))

fit <- mle(LL1, start = unlist(inits))
```